# Is there an orbit map without path lifting property?

Tags: gn.general-topology, lie-groups, topological-groups, foliations

I am looking for an example of a topological group $G$ acting by homeomorphisms on a metrizable space $X$ such that the orbit map $X\to X/G$ doesn't have the path lifting property, that is, there is a path in $X/G$ that cannot be lifted to $X$.

EDIT: Let's also assume that every $G$-orbit is a closed subset.

**Non-example:** If $G$ is a compact Lie group, then the orbit map has the path lifting property (in fact, there is a a slice). Palais gave a generalization to proper Lie group actions.

Comment: How about $\mathbb{Z}$ acting on $S^1$ by an irrational rotation? The induced topology on $S^1/\mathbb{Z}$ is indiscrete, so we can make a path that just jumps from one point to another. This cannot be lifted to $S^1$ because every path in $S^1$ is either constant or its range is all of $S^1/\mathbb{Z}$ under the quotient map.

Comment: Thank you! Dense orbit is enough. I was focused on the case of closed orbits.

Comment: I think, there are even examples even when $G$ is compact and the action is free, but, of course, $G$ is not a Lie group. Check the example I gave in my answer [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/23478/examples-of-common-false-beliefs-in-mathematics/237093#237093).

Comment: @MoisheKohan: I don't know why a path lifting property (for the orbit map of a free action by a compact group) has to imply the map is a principal bundle (or fibration). Ruling our principal bundles is much easier, see Remark 2 in https://mathoverflow.net/questions/57015/which-principlal-bundles-are-locally-trivial.

Comment: Remark: the question doesn't refer to any topology on $G$ (still, the "non-example" says that the lifting property holds assuming that $G$ carries some group topology such that the action is continuous, plus some extra-assumptions).

Comment: @YCor: not sure what you are saying. As stated, the question is about any topological group, and non-example says that the desired group cannot be a compact Lie group, or more generally Lie group that acts Palais-properly. Naturally, a simpler example would be better. All I want is to gain intuition on paths that don't lift.

Comment: This is not what I am saying: I am saying that there is a good chance that this example does not have a path-lifting property. In this example, a totally disconnected group acts on a 1-dimensional space such that the quotient is 2-dimensional.